# Dapper QueryFirstOrDefault not available

Tags: c#, .net, dapper

Trying out Dapper and I am able to do this:

```
Query
QueryMultiple
Query<T>
QueryAsync
QueryAsyc<T>
```

But `QueryFirstOrDefault`, as well as all other queries not listed above are not available.

I have Dapper and Dapper Async installed via NUGET and I have `using Dapper;` at the top. Am I missing a using or a package that has these other queries in them?

[image]

UPDATE: I went back down from 1.50.5 to a lower version and then back up to 1.50.5 and now it's working - a bad NUGET install the first time?

Comment: That's odd because the definition for `QueryFirstOrDefault` is literally in the same file as `Query`.  When you say your able to do those do you mean intellisense only shows those extension methods for `IDbConnection`?

Comment: @juharr Yes, see attached picture.

Comment: @Crowcoder Z.Dapper.Plus didn't help.

Comment: Yeah, i just checked and it is included so I don't know.

Comment: Dapper Plus seems to be completely unrelated to Dapper, other than the name.

Answer (score 0):

try typing "QueryFirstOrDefault" and then right click and see if there is something else the IDE recommends to add to "use".

**EDIT:**
 You are getting this error because you have not added the namespace using **System.Linq** in your cs file. Try to **explicit declare Dapper**. QueryFirstOrDefault

Comment: I see that you can use the Linq `FirstOrDefault`, but Dapper is supposed to have these methods, so why am I missing them?

Comment: So that is your issue my friend

You are getting this error because you have not added the namespace

using System.Linq
in your cs file.

Try to explicit declare Dapper. QueryFirstOrDefault

Comment: I got it working by reinstalling the nuget package. I had System.Linq imported and can actually remove that and `QueryFirstOrDefault` still works.